# Show important items on the top or put it in the right hierarchy where it belongs

Tags: website-design, navigation, hierarchy

I'm working on a website for a TV show, and according to the UX research one thing I found out was that people look out for some pages like "scripts" , "quotes", "nicknames of characters" etc..

I initially planned out to put it according to the hierarchy for e,g

- Seasons > Episode > Quotes In That Episode + Script etc...

But I'm wondering whether it would bury the information people are looking for.

Should i put up the important pages users want in the front , if so how do i do so without breaking up the navigation. Any advice on how to make present it in a usable and meaningful way would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website is not too complex you can always have different ways to structure the information, like besides what you suggested you could have:

Quotes > Quotes by character / by season

Scripts > Choose Season > Choose episode

Comment: This is exactly what i had in mind but I doubted whether it was the right way. I think this serves right because according to this, i could have a have a quotes page as the main menu item which is sorted by season and also find quotes for a specific season by going to the season page.

Answer (score 0):

Putting non trivival content and categories like this - that only a segment of the users are looking for - in the hierarchy seems like a good basic solution. But few users looks for content in a menu, that they wont expect to be there, and few user's browse menues to explorer and discover interesting and fun content like this.
So, I'll suggest, in addition to nesting the content and categories in the hierarchy, that you feature the content more prominently in the design. Eg. with a box of "Quote of the week", "A special scene fromt this week", "Selected nicknames" etc. these can serve as more inspirational entries to the content.

Comment: A very good suggestions. Thanks jesper, I really like the idea on how we could give tiny pieces of relevant content linking up to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will probably bury the information. As @JesperVestergaard said, few users look for content in a menu.

What you should worry about, in my opinion, is that this Quotes are accessible through the **Search**. Users have become very dependent on the search to navigate on a website, they don't want to search manually for the information... The website itself must do this job for them.

As @TalyEmmanuela said, you should also have **redundancy** on getting the information. You can have your "[Seasons > Episode > Quotes In That Episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1589921/quotes)" page for those looking for quotes from a specific episode, but you should also have a "Seasons > Main Quotes In That Season" page and event a "[Main Quotes In The TV Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1520211/quotes)" page. All of them are "Quotes page", but the **context** defines the filter (sorry for the TWD links, I needed an example).

I would also suggest you to order the quotes by importance / access / favorites (whatever your site offers) to help the user to find the quote they want (see the example of "X users found this interesting" from IMDB).

Comment: Thanks for this dinei, I knew this cud done but just wanted to ensure whether it is the right way to do it.